# adding another login to stack?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

I've used myopenid but it has had troubles recently and I'd like to add another login to stack.

I tried creating new account to stack but now the system wants me to logout the old login when trying to add another login to my account. I tried logging in with stack and adding the openid and vice versa. Same result. Logout old connection first.

Any help?

Comment: nada.  Browser close and reopen. Stack Exchange - my account - add more logins - stack exchange: You are currently logged in.
Do you want to log out and log in with this OpenID?

Comment: Cancel: Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

Comment: @anttir it sounds to me like the other openid you are using is *already* registered, but to a separate account. When you log in with both, do you get different userid/accountid ?

Comment: Yes, it is. First I tried getting new stackexchange account for my myopenid account, but there was no register button. So I had to logout, create new stackexchange account and try to combine these.

Comment: @anttir we have the ability to merge separate accounts, but you'll need to let me know which ones. Either here, or email me at marc@stackexchange.com

Comment: k; try logging out and back in now

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, works!

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please add a reply so we can mark this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this will "just work" - I.e. you can add multiple openid to your account. In this case, you seem to have two separate accounts - no problem: we have a supercomputer in the basement which knows how to merge accounts. It used lasers, and oddly, Pringles. We don't know why this is, but we do know that it doesn't work without both.